# How to get iPhone Birthdays calendar to show up in Windows 11 Calendar

Tags: iphone, windows, calendar, icloud

I am on Windows 11 using the windows calendar app (not outlook). I was able to add my iCloud account to get the 'Home' and 'Work' calendars from my iPhone to show up. But, the Birhdays calendar does not show up. See below. Birthdays is listed under OTHER instead of ICLOUD, so not sure if there are additional steps required?

[image]